# how to get date format only Hours, Minutes, and second

Tags: php, laravel

[output from 'in.attendance_time as in_time', 'out.attendance_time as out_time',](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pWJHW.png)

```
    $absen = DB::table('attendance as in')
                            ->where('in.in_out', 'in')
                            ->where('in.company_id', \Session::get('selected_company'))
                            ->whereDate('in.created', Carbon::today())
                            ->leftJoin('attendance as out', function ($join) {
                                $join->on('in.employee_id', 'out.employee_id')
                                    ->where('out.in_out', 'out')
                                    ->where('out.company_id', \Session::get('selected_company'))
                                    ->whereDate('out.created', Carbon::today());
                            })
                            ->join('employee', 'employee.id', 'in.employee_id')
                            ->join('location_library', 'location_library.id', 'in.attendance_location_id')
                            ->join('company as cp', 'cp.id', 'in.company_id')
                            ->join('employee_in_app as e_app', 'e_app.employee_id', 'in.employee_id')
                            ->join('employee_in_company', 'in.employee_id', 'employee_in_company.employee_id')
                            ->select('employee.name', 'cp.alias', 'in.employee_id','location_library.location_name',  'in.attendance_time as in_time', 'out.attendance_time as out_time', 'e_app.note')
                            ->orderBy('in.attendance_time', 'DESC')
                            ->get();
```

I want to retrieve only hours, minutes and seconds without the date, month and year in the select, how to solve this problem? data showing date is 'in.attendance_time as in_time', 'out.attendance_time as out_time',

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use This `DB::raw` query for formating date

```
->select('employee.name', 'cp.alias', 'in.employee_id','location_library.location_name',  DB::raw('DATE_FORMAT(in.attendance_time, "%H-%i-%s") as in_time'), DB::raw('DATE_FORMAT(out.attendance_time, "%H-%i-%s") as out_time'), 'e_app.note')
```